# gridview DropDownList selected value problem

Tags: asp.net

work on asp.net vs05.I take a gridview and under the RowDataBount fill the dropDownList.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="StudentID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView3_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="GridView3_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="StudentID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="StudentID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentName" HeaderText="StudentName" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DivisionName">
                    <EditItemTemplate>

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="160px">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" HeaderText="Update" Text="Update" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>



DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");

            studentInfos ostudentInfos = new studentInfos();
            BOstudentInfo oBOstudentInfo = new BOstudentInfo();
            ostudentInfos = oBOstudentInfo.Gets();           
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "StudentName";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "StudentName";
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "StudentName";

            foreach (studentInfo oItem in ostudentInfos)
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(oItem.StudentName);


            }
```

then use selectedIndexChanged Event

```
  GridViewRow selectRow = GridView3.SelectedRow;
        String ID = selectRow.Cells[0].Text;
        String Name = selectRow.Cells[1].Text;
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList) selectRow.FindControl("DropDownList1");

         string s = ddl.SelectedValue;
```

**On this event why i always get selectedIndex=0 and SelectedValue=first element of the list.**

Answer (score 1):

Use **IsPostBack** page property.

```
if(!IsPostBack){
  .....
 foreach (studentInfo oItem in ostudentInfos){
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(oItem.StudentName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
String id = row.Cells[0].Text;
string requestid = ((Label)row.FindControl("Label1")).Text;
string type = ddl.SelectedValue;
```